# xml dom to mysql with empty value

Tags: php, mysql, xml

This is my PHP code to import XML File into MySQL table:

```
<?php

sleep(3);
$output = '';
$fileXML = 'archivi/clienti.xml';

if (isset($fileXML) && $fileXML != '')
    {
    $valid_extension = array(
        'xml'
    );
    $file_data = explode('.', $fileXML);
    $file_extension = end($file_data);
    if (in_array($file_extension, $valid_extension))
        {
        $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
        $xmlDoc->load($fileXML);
        $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=otc', 'root', 'root');
        $xmlObject = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('cliente');
        $itemCount = $xmlObject->length;
        print_r($xmlObject);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $itemCount; $i++)
            {
            $codice = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('codice')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $ragione_sociale = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('ragione_sociale')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $indirizzo = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('indirizzo')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $cap = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('cap')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $citta = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('citta')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $prov = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('prov')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $piva = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('piva')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
            if (!empty($cfisc = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('cfisc')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue))
                {
                echo 'not empty';
                }
              else
                {
                echo 'is not set or empty';
                $cfisc = ' ';
                }

            $sql = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO clienti (codice, ragione_sociale,indirizzo,cap,citta,prov,piva,cfisc ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $sql->execute(array(
                $codice,
                $ragione_sociale,
                $indirizzo,
                $cap,
                $citta,
                $prov,
                $piva,
                $cfisc
            ));
            print "Finished Item $title n<br/>";
            }
        }
      else
        {
        $output = '<div class="alert alert-warning">Invalid File</div>';
        }
    }
  else
    {
    $output = '<div class="alert alert-warning">Please Select XML File</div>';
    }

echo $output;

?>
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<elenco_clienti>
    <cliente>
        <codice>00001</codice>
        <ragione_sociale>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</ragione_sociale>
        <indirizzo>yyyyyyyyyyy</indirizzo>
        <cap>000000</cap>
        <citta>xxxxxxxx</citta>
        <prov>xx</prov>
        <piva>000000000</piva>
        <cfisc/>
        <luogo_nasc/>
        <data_nasc>01011900</data_nasc>
        <sesso>A</sesso>
        <tele>00000000</tele>
        <cell/>
        <mail>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</mail>
        <cod_card/>
        <cod_card1/>
        <punti_card>0</punti_card>
    </cliente>
</elenco_clienti>
```

The problem is `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in line 31` because the value is empty.

How to get empty value and put in my database?

I try with PHP simplexml also but I have the same result when try to get value like `<cod_card></cod_card>`. I get the above error.

Comment: Probably not related but... did you even notice you are trying to write 7 values into 8 fields?

Comment: prepare the sql insert statement once before you enter the loop and execute multiple times within the loop

Comment: On line 31 there is a closing bracket `}`: please review your code or update the error message accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One of the key points about `prepared statements` is that you prepare the statement object once and execute as many times as needed simply by changing the values assigned to the bound parameters. To that end, prepare the statement outside the loop and if the statement is successfully created bind placeholders to variables. The variables at this point do not need to exist - they are created later inside the loop after which the statement can be executed.

The accessing of childnode values could be simplified by use of a sinple function - not tested but looks like it ought to work ok. I updated the function `getchildvalue` to test for childnodes and return an empty string if none exist which should prevent the error warning of `Trying to get property of non-object`

```
<?php

    $output = array();
    $file = 'archivi/clienti.xml';

    if( !empty( $file ) ) {

        $valid_extension = array('xml');
        $ext=pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ); # much simpler method to get file extension


        function getchildvalue( $node, $tag ){
            return $node->getElementsByTagName( $tag )->item(0)->childNodes->length> 0 ? $node->getElementsByTagName( $tag )->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue : '';
        }


        if( in_array( $ext, $valid_extension ) ) {

            $dom = new DOMDocument();
            $dom->load( $file );

            /* connect & prepare sql */
            $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=otc', 'root', 'root');
            $sql='insert into `clienti` (`codice`,`ragione_sociale`,`indirizzo`,`cap`,`citta`,`prov`,`piva`,`cfisc` ) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
            $stmt=$connect->prepare( $sql );

            if( $stmt ){
                /* statement OK - bind parameters to variables */

                /* UPDATE: incremented each by +1 ~ these are not zero based as initially thought */

                $stmt->bindParam(1,$codice);
                $stmt->bindParam(2,$ragione_sociale);
                $stmt->bindParam(3,$indirizzo);
                $stmt->bindParam(4,$cap);
                $stmt->bindParam(5,$citta);
                $stmt->bindParam(6,$prov);
                $stmt->bindParam(7,$piva);
                $stmt->bindParam(8,$cfisc);

                /* get DOM nodes */
                $col = $dom->getElementsByTagName('cliente');
                foreach( $col as $node ){
                    try{
                        /* get values of child nodes */
                        $codice = getchildvalue( $node, 'codice');
                        $ragione_sociale = getchildvalue( $node, 'ragione_sociale');
                        $indirizzo = getchildvalue( $node, 'indirizzo');
                        $cap = getchildvalue( $node, 'cap');
                        $citta = getchildvalue( $node, 'citta');
                        $prov = getchildvalue( $node, 'prov');
                        $piva = getchildvalue( $node, 'piva');
                        $cfisc = getchildvalue( $node, 'cfisc');

                        if( empty( $cfisc ) ) $output[]='cfisc is empty';

                        /* execute sql statement */
                        $stmt->execute();


                        $output[]="Finished Item $title";   //  ?where is $title defined?
                    }catch( Exception $e ){
                        $output[]=$e->getMessage();
                    }
                }

                $stmt->closeCursor();

            } else {
                $output[]='sql failed preparation';
            }
        } else {
            $output[]='<div class="alert alert-warning">Invalid File</div>';
        }
    } else {
        $output[]='<div class="alert alert-warning">Please Select XML File</div>';
    }        
    echo $output;
?>
```

Example of reading xml file

```
<?php


    function getchildvalue( $node, $tag, $rv=false ){
        /*
            $rv = return value
            specify default value to return if node does
            not contain any content
        */
        return $node->getElementsByTagName( $tag )->item(0)->childNodes->length> 0 ? $node->getElementsByTagName( $tag )->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue : ( $rv ? $rv : '' );
    }


    $xml='<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <elenco_clienti>
        <cliente>
            <codice>00001</codice>
            <ragione_sociale>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</ragione_sociale>
            <indirizzo>yyyyyyyyyyy</indirizzo>
            <cap>000000</cap>
            <citta>xxxxxxxx</citta>
            <prov>xx</prov>
            <piva>000000000</piva>
            <cfisc/>
            <luogo_nasc/>
            <data_nasc>01011900</data_nasc>
            <sesso>A</sesso>
            <tele>00000000</tele>
            <cell/>
            <mail>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</mail>
            <cod_card/>
            <cod_card1/>
            <punti_card>0</punti_card>
        </cliente>
    </elenco_clienti>';

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML( $xml );

    $col = $dom->getElementsByTagName('cliente');
    foreach( $col as $node ){

        $codice = getchildvalue( $node, 'codice', 'codice is empty');
        $ragione_sociale = getchildvalue( $node, 'ragione_sociale', 'ragione_sociale is empty');
        $indirizzo = getchildvalue( $node, 'indirizzo');
        $cap = getchildvalue( $node, 'cap');
        $citta = getchildvalue( $node, 'citta');
        $prov = getchildvalue( $node, 'prov');
        $piva = getchildvalue( $node, 'piva');
        $cfisc = getchildvalue( $node, 'cfisc', 'big yellow banana' );/* <------ set alernate return value */


        echo $codice.' '.$ragione_sociale.' '.$indirizzo .' ' .$cap.' '.$citta.' '.$prov.' '.$piva.' '.$cfisc;
    }
?>
```

The output from the above

```
00001 xxxxxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyyyy 000000 xxxxxxxx xx 000000000 big yellow banana
```

Comment: don't workWarning: PDOStatement::bindParam(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: Columns/Parameters are 1-based in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/otc/good/raf_index.php on line 29

Comment: I tend never to use that syntax so they might not be zero based (`0`) ~ try starting at `1` ~ the main point of the above though was to address the error you were getting `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: What you suggest For parsing my XML?